# Best way to display static text in a view RubyMotion

Tags: rubymotion

I have a two view app.  The root view has items that simply have a details view.  In that details view is a simple section label (the item name) followed by a paragraph description.

What is the best way to display this static text?  Is the best option UILabel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually a UILabel works fine. Make sure you set the lineBreakMode to zero (0) so it will wrap.